# What is a good way to add percentage to my java program?

Tags: java

I have to write a Java class to implement [Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law).

I can't figure out how to do the last part: "for each digit, output the percentage it appears as the first digit"

Could I get some help with this please?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.File;

public class BenfordLaw {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] arrayOfData = new String[125];//Array creation
    // Read inn from the text file
    Scanner input = null;



    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File("worldPopulations.csv"));//instantiation

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File was not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);

    }//end try catch block
    input.nextLine(); //so we can skip it

    int index = 0;
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(Line);
        arrayOfData[index] = line;
        index++;

    }
    input.close();

    int[] count = new int[9];//setting limit for array


    //Now process our data
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfData.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayOfData[i]);//tests to see that we filled the array correctly
        //find the first char in our string
        char firstChar = arrayOfData[i].charAt(0);
        int firstDigit = firstChar - '0';
        System.out.println(firstDigit);
        count[firstDigit - 1]++;

    }//end arrayOfData.length

    //look at the count of each digit
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number of digit" + (i+1) + "'s is " + count[i] );
    }



}//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: While it might be a tad difficult for a newcomer to master, this type of problem seems to be a good case for the Java 8 streams API. Just something to consider.

Comment: You're supposed to print the frequency of the appearance of 0-9 in the input file you've been given.  What's so difficult?  I would expect a Map where the key is 0-9 and the value is the number of input values that start with that digit.  You calculate frequency by dividing the number of input values that start with that digit by the total number of input values.

Comment: @duffymo isn't frequency the amount of times something occurs over time?

Comment: Not in this case. If you read in 100 numbers, how many would start with 0,1,2,3...?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close to a solution. You have the `counts` array that holds how many times in your data set each digit (1-9) appears as the first digit. If you sum those counts (use a loop), then you can use that total as the denominator when calculating the percentage (count / total * 100) for each digit.

Make sure you cast the count to a floating point number before doing the division, or you'll get truncated results from integer division.